# Meteor - adding up vote to specific id in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a site that lets users add urls with descriptions to a collection. When they add a site the url, title, description as well as user and date created go into a collection by using:

```
Collection.insert({
        url:siteUrl,
        title: siteTitle,
        description: siteDescription,
        createdOn:Date(),
        createdBy:Meteor.user()._id

});
```

I want to add up/down vote. I have created a Template event so when they click on up or down I create a var with the website _id. I am new to meteor and db's in general so my question is once I have the website _id in a variable how can I add an up or down to that _id?

Comment: Have you done any research at all on this? There are many examples out there, and it is really not our place here to tell you which specific method you should be using. Since you don't appear to have made any attempt at integrating this into your structure, this is a bit too broad.

Comment: @BlakesSeven  I have done some research but did not understand them very well. I'm still learning meteor and programming in general. My apologies.

Comment: It's not a fault to apologise for, but just a reality that answers here will not likely cover the scope of things you **need** to consider in an upvoting system i.e, stoping multiple votes from the same person just as one. Responses would be either 1. irresponsibly misinformative and oversimplified 2. very opion based to structure and handling 3. generally too broad as a definitive how to and all considerations guide. So I really think you are better off searching for previous posts and examples of different things people are doing. That way you **learn**, rather than copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the increment `$inc` operator:

```
Collection.update({_id: myId},{$inc: {vote: +1}}); // for a vote UP
Collection.update({_id: myId},{$inc: {vote: -1}}); // for a vote DOWN
```

Comment: The + operator `vote: +1` isn't necessary to be very pedantic.

Comment: Yes obviously but it helps make the point, especially with `+1` having entered the English lexicon as a positive reinforcement.